# Existe alguna api para el tipo de cambio en Argentina?

Tags: api

seguramente esta pregunta este mal forumalada de ser asi acepto ediciones, pero no sabia como formularla. Estaba buscando una API para le tipo de cambio de Dolar en Argentina. Tengo entendido que la API del banco central no da mas servicio, asi que estaba buscando otra para implementar pero no pude encontrar ninguna que parezca bastante solida. Espero sus sugerencias si desean ayudarme.

Comment: Recordá que las preguntas amplias / basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas. Podrías preguntar en el chat del sitio, donde la temática es más abierta.

Comment: Gracias, no estaba al tanto que existía un chat. Lo tendre en cuenta.

Comment: [Esta es la sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).